# C++ Read File with multiple column

Tags: c++

I'd like to read a file with multiple columns, different variable types. The number of columns is uncertain, but between 2 or four. So for instance, I have a file with :

> - string int
> - string int string double
> - string int string
> - string int string double

Thanks!

I edited to correct the number of columns to between 2 or 5, not 4 or five as originally written.

Comment: So you want us to write you code? You're not paying us? So please do research and ask questions here about specific problems you encounter along the way.

Comment: How are the columns divided? If with whitespace (space or tab) then the normal input operator `>>` will work fine.

Comment: *The number of columns is uncertain, but between 4 or five* --- yet your example shows that the first row only contains 2 columns, and not a single one contains 5 columns!

Comment: 1) read a line. 2) tokenize it somehow. 3) come back if you have a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first read the line with [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

```
std::ifstream f("file.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(f, line)) {
...
}
```

and then parse this line with a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

```
std::string col1, col3;
int col2;
double col4;
std::istringstream ss(line);
ss >> col1 >> col2;
if (ss >> col3) {
    // process column 3
    if (ss >> col4) {
        // process column 4
    }
}
```

If the columns might contain different types, you must first read into a string and then try to determine the proper type.

Comment: Don't forget `#include <sstream>`